# Sending HTTP Request with app - AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, http

I would like to send HTTP requests from my android app when pushing a button to an ESP8266 which is waiting for any webpage to be accessed, however i would prefer if my android app didn't actually open the webpage but rather just "send an HTTP Request"

Right now I'm using;

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_QUICK_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.201/onled")));
```

and it is working, but obviously it is opening the webpage...

Anyone have a good suggestion on how to solve my problem? i am new at java.

Comment: Instead of HTML command, I think you are looking for the term *HTTP request*

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request

Answer (score 2):

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
        private Exception exception;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{
                URL url= new URL("http://yourserveraddress/resource.extension");
                HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //write additional POST data to url.getOutputStream() if you wanna use POST method 
            }catch (Exception ex){
                this.exception=ex;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the HTTP connection and HTTP request.

You can do it in a few ways:

- use `HttpURLConnection` available natively in the Java - see this tutorial for details: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/
- use a dedicated library, which does the same thing in a slightly better way - e.g. [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Please remember that sending HTTP request is non-deterministic operation and you should execute it in a separate, non-UI thread to keep UI unblocked. You can do it via [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask), which is the simplest solution, but you can also use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) with [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) or other approaches.

Comment: G...! I knew I was just asking the wrong question! I'll have a look at the guides you linked too and see what I can work out! 
Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to send HTTP Requests from an app. For example using `HttpURLConnection` with `GET` method you can proceed as follows:

```java
 StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL u1 = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection uc1 = (HttpURLConnection) u1.openConnection();
            if (uc1.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream is = uc1.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    content.append(line).append("\n");

                }

            }//other codes
```

You can find simplified ways to do so with Google most sophisticated methods:

[Find the reference here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#java)